# Make a post to a login form of a webpage using C# in Xamarin and Android

Tags: c#, post, xamarin, xamarin.android, http-post

I just started learning C#, and I have also never experienced in developing mobile environments. I have experience in Java and I could adopt some knowledge from there.

I have VisualStudio 2017RC, and started a Xamarin.Android project. Furthermore there is a ASP.NET site for registration and login, and token generation (SQLite user storage). My goal is to make a view in xamarin where the user can type his/her name and password then can login to the website where he/she get an access token.

I have already made a LoginView, it was a piece of cake...
Now I have to post the filled data to the website and log in to the page using c# in Xamarin.Android. Lets see how far I have got to.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginWebview);

    //code for getting the login details(emial, password) from the user
    //code for getting the access token
    //apiBaseUri is fixed value

    MainAsync(email, password, apiBaseUri, loginToken).Wait();
}


public static async Task MainAsync(string email, string password, string apiBaseUri, string loginToken)
{
    var token = await GetApiTokenAsync(email, password, apiBaseUri, loginToken);
}

public static async Task<string> GetApiTokenAsync(string email, string password, string apiBaseUri, string tokenValue)
{
    var token = string.Empty;

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false
    };


    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

        //set cookie
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Set-Cookie", CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(apiBaseUri));

        //setup login data
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
 //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Email", username),
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", password),
 new KeyValuePair<string,string>("__RequestVerificationToken",tokenValue),
 new KeyValuePair<string,string>("RememberMe","false")
          });

        //send request               
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("/Login?returnurl=%2FGame%2Fkz%2FToken", formContent);
        var responseJson = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
        token = jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();

        return token;
    }

}
}
```

Well at line

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("/Login?returnurl=%2FGame%2Fkz%2FToken", formContent);
```

The program hangs and I got no access token back.

Let's see the issue from the website point of view: in the webbrowser the login form can be opened with the following link: (I will use some dummy value ("game") in the url in order to keep it private)
http://www.game.nl/PlayGame/kz/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FGame%2Fkz%2Ftoken

With opening this website I can type the email and the password. Then If I click on the log in button I got an access token (which will be used for later purposes). I would like to get to this point, but of course in c# with android phone

I am going to list some additional info about the website  because I think they are also relevant to the solution.
The details are the following, if I log in with the website. (I check the details with Google Chrome developer tool, at network tab)

General:

- Request
  URL:http://www.game.nl/PlayGame/kz/Account/Login?returnurl=%2FGame%2Fkz%2Ftoken
- Request Method:POST
- Status Code:302 Found
- Remote Address:(private)

FormData:

- Email:example@company.nl
- Password:chocolate09#
- __RequestVerificationToken:CfDJ8L1aKkmfKmBLlQIwHTacxWKOtRekEcOfxKQGBrXUEkE2XpWyxYmMKOTlgZ7gCZq3FEx8ILF_VgQcsjBztZhCwUUYSV966s1BgjFs5I8IefGSoei5hfzK-WQQr8Ztjpn3oGq40neXx4_iBUUMRjFpKz_DdBqzQ
- RememberMe:false

The source of the form data:

> Email=example%40company.nl&Password=chocolate09%23&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8L1aKkmfKmBLlQIwHTacxWKOtRekEcOfxKQGBrXUEkE2XpWyxYmMKOTlgZ7gCZq3FEx8ILF_VgQcsjBztZhCwUUYSV966s1BgjFs5I8IefGSoei5hfzK-WQQr8Ztjpn3oGq40neXx4_iBUUMRjFpKz_DdBqzQ&RememberMe=false

So I am stuck at this point, and I do not know why it hangs at

```
await client.PostAsync("/Login?returnurl=%2FGame%2Fkz%2FToken", formContent);
```

The last lines of the VS console output:

```
02-11 00:07:01.404 D/Mono    ( 2853): [0x982bf930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
02-11 00:07:07.829 D/Mono    ( 2853): [0x9847f930] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
The thread 'Unknown' (0x4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem I believe is this line in `OnCreate`:

`MainAsync(email, password, apiBaseUri, loginToken).Wait();`

Specifically the `.Wait()` statement. `OnCreate` is always called on the UI thread. Whenever you use async/await and wait for the result using `.Wait()` or `.Result` bad things happen and your app will hang as the continuation cannot jump back to the UI thread - and you will see this in the call to `PostAsync` as this is the first call that will actually use a different thread to run on.

I guess the reason you are calling `.Wait()` is because `OnCreate` is not an async method - well the good news is it can be. I would mark it as `async` and `await` the login (you can mark void methods as async, there are pitfalls with doing so, so be sure to catch all exceptions inside the method!)

```
// Mark the method as async
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginWebview);

    // remove the .Wait() and await the method call
    await MainAsync(email, password, apiBaseUri, loginToken);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now I can go on... But unfortunately I got a 404 not found error in the 'responseJson', which is strange for me...What is your opinion about it?